# SQL-Delete records with non latin characters

Tags: sql

I have a table with about 15 columns, one of which contains data that may have non latin characters (specifically, Chinese, Korean and Russian).  Is there way to delete each record for which any non English or Latin Characters exist in a specified column?

Ultimately, the table needs to contain English only...
Thank you for any help

Comment: What DBMS it is?

Comment: Sorry - 
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio v  14